# How to ignore punctuations and symbols appended to a word, so that they are all treated as same when considering for word count?

Tags: java, regex, string, java-8

I am writing a program for word count of each word in any text file.
**The contents of file are NOT known before-hand.**

**Desired Output :** 
e.g.
***[book] [book!] [book-] [book?] [book,] [book's]*** and the likes to be treated as same for word count.

**Current Output :** 
***book=2, book.=1, book--=1, book?=5, book's=3, book,=2, book!=1***

When I am actually looking for **book=15**

```
 try(Stream<String> fileContents = Files.lines(filePath)){

            Function<String, Stream<String>> splitIntoWords = line -> Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream(line);

            Map<String, Long> wordFrequency = fileContents.flatMap(splitIntoWords)
                                .filter(word -> word.trim().length() > 4) //Consider only Words with length greater than 4
                                .map(String::toLowerCase)
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));


            System.out.println(wordFrequency);
}
```

I do not wish to hard-code specific symbols and punctuations in regex to ignore, since the exact contents of file is not known.

Is there any generic way to accomplish this?

Comment: `\[(\w+)\W*?\w*?\]` you can try this  https://regex101.com/r/Z4bUJ7/1 check here

Comment: Thanks! That was quick and perfect :)

Comment: @CodeManiac while this works for some cases, it will fail in many others: `\w` generally matches `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`. So as long as you want numbers and underscores to be part of your words and you don't work with languages using diacritics (`ä, é, ...`) it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pattern.compile("\\P{L}+").split ...`
This would split at any character (or more than one) which is NOT a letter of any language. I guess this gets you what you want?

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome :) I think this is a neat little elegant regex for quick use if you need to tokenize text by words in a simple manner. I use it a lot myself.